# option for wi-fi disappeared

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

On ubuntu 16.04 LTS, etc/network/interfaces file used to be like this **(not sure)**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Than some time I had to use usb wi-fi adapter for long range etc, for that I changed interfaces to

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback
iface wlp3s0 inet manual
```

while returning to system's wifi card I toggle interfaces like

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback
iface wlp3s0 inet manual
```

It used to work fine, now when I turn back to system's wifi card, it don't even show **Enable Wifi** option
[image: while on system's wifi card]

And this is result of `ifconfig -a`
[image: ifconfig -a]

**without this line**

```
iface wlp3s0 inet manual
```

**usb wifi adapter used to not work, now even of I clear interfaces file, it still keep on working.**

Let me know that did I messed up with interfaces or what is the issue here.

Comment: If output of any command required kindly let me know

Comment: turned out its not issue with interfaces file but "Canonical updated HWE stack for Ubuntu 16.04 to the 4.15 kernel. But they forgot to update the Broadcom wireless driver" as explained by @Pilot6
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052403/how-can-i-fix-broadcom-driver-wifi-with-4-15-0-24-kernel-on-ubuntu-16-04